# What is best option for read only database for iPhone app?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to make some information app where user can ready only data.DB contains text only paragraph + 1 picture in each row. My question is, what is good way of doing it? I will need to add more data to DB with more information in future.

Let say if my database size is 30-40MB, is it good to put all together in app? Like preload SQlite and attach that to app.

I would like to know if I create my own server, is it worth it because it's  not big Database and no need to save user data either.

Comment: If you don't put any code in your program that writes to the database, the database is effectively read-only, isn't it?

Comment: I am doing which said as this tutorial to preload SQlite DB ....http://hubpages.com/hub/Tutorial-on-Creating-an-IOS-5-SQLite-Database-Application-IOS-5-SQLite

Answer (score 0):

30-40MB doesn't hit the limit for iOS OTA downloads but it is a bit bulky.  If it is a static DB though have you considered just putting it on S3?  Try the following:

1. Create a JSON file with the data structured the way you would like and put it on a public S3 link.  For the images use URLs that are also hosted on S3  (or whatever file server you want to use to serve this...I only say S3 because it is pretty ubiquitous).
2. When the app launches go and grab the JSON file like so:

   ```
   NSURL *pathToJSON = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl..."];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pathToJSON];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
       NSError *error;
       id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
   }];
   ```

You can then choose to either download and cache the images locally right away or just fetch them as needed.  This way you get all the benefits of server updating without needing to maintain a true API server.

Comment: Yes I never though this way , thanks smyrgl, Is renting server is good option? Like Parse? So that will remove whole point of updating DB with app update as Data base is located separately , isn't it??

Comment: Parse is fine but it's still a database.  As a rule of thumb if you feel like the updates need to be incremental then you should look at a real DB and an API.  If you just need to push binary package updates to your clients then S3 is MUCH simpler.